# How to loop over array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to loop over this array of objects to render them in a component in react, why the mapping is not working?

fruits:[{"value":"Apple","status":"Green"},{"value":"Orange ","status":"Yellow"},{"value":"Banana","status":"Green"}]

```
export interface FruitsStatus { 
  fruits: Record<string, string>;
}
const Fruits: (props: FruitsStatus) => JSX.Element = props => {
return (
{props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    {fruit.value}
                  </td>
                  <td > {fruit.status} </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error or something else? What do you expect and what do you see instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because there is no root tag to contain all tr tags

simply wrap it with fragment :

```
return (
   <>
     {props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    {fruit.value}
                  </td>
                  <td > {fruit.status} </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
   </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface FruitsStatus { 
  fruits: Record<string, string>[];
}
const Fruits: (props: FruitsStatus) => JSX.Element = props => {
return (
{props.fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    {fruit.value}
                  </td>
                  <td > {fruit.status} </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
)
}
```

FruitStatus.fruits have to be an array instead of a single record.